# Using C macros in Objective-C to alloc-init

Tags: objective-c

This question is out of curiosity, and for my own amusement rather than whether it's a good idea or not, but coming from a mostly C#/JavaScript background, constantly seeing this in Objective-C strikes me as kind of ugly:

```
MyClass* myObj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

...and I'm curious if it would be possible to define a C-style macro such that this could be turned into this:

```
MyClass* myObj = new MyClass;
```

...or something syntactically similar.

Has anyone done this or seen it done before? Feel free to comment as to why it might be a horrible idea (besides the obvious one that it's non-standard and unfamiliar), but that's not going to stop me wanting to know if it can be done. ;)

Comment: You might be interested to know that NSObject also [implements](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/new) `+new` so you can do `MyClass *myObj = [MyClass new];`. It's not as commonly seen as alloc/init, but it's perfectly valid. EDIT: And, Carl was updating his answer with this info as I was writing this comment...

Comment: Here's a good article on using C macros in Obj-C (and the dangers of doing so): http://weblog.highorderbit.com/post/11656225202/appropriate-use-of-c-macros-for-objective-c-developers

Answer (score 7):

You could certainly make this work:

```
#define new(x) [[x alloc] init]
MyClass *myObj = new(MyClass);
```

If you need to do it without the parentheses I think you're out of luck.

`NSObject` provides a `new` class method, though.  So you can already do this, if you happen to like it better:

```
MyClass *myObj = [MyClass new];
```

Here's a link to the [relevant documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/new).

Comment: Cool. That's kind of what I was hoping. The parentheses don't particularly bother me.

Comment: NO NO NO, GOD NO.  There's a reason why code like this doesn't ship.

Comment: @CodaFi, I'm with you.  OP says he's aware it might be a horrible idea, but that certainly doesn't mean it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Why write `MyClass *myObj = new(MyClass);` if you could use

```
#define createObject(className, objectName) className *objectName = [[className alloc] init]
```

and

```
createObject(NSObject, obj);
```

Your code certainly becomes even less readable. You could then create macros for other initialisers like `initWith...:`

Just because something can be done, doesn't mean that it should. It is generally a good idea to write readable code, not short code.

Comment: I'm mostly curious to get an idea for where the boundaries and limitations lie between C, Objective-C (and to a lesser extent C++). For example, Obj-C doesn't support operator overloading, so I was just curious if it fully supported macros. Of course I'm aware most people would disagree with me on the use of them. ;)

Comment: Objective-C is a strict superset of C, so everything you can do in C (including macros) can be done in Objective-C.